# How to compress 300GB file using python

Tags: python, compression

I am trying to compress a virtual machine file with size 300GB.

Every single time the python script is killed because the actually memory usage of
the `gzip` module exceeds 30GB (virtual memory).

Is there any way to achieve large file(300GB to 64TB) compression using python?

```
def gzipFile(fileName):
  startTime = time.time()
  with  open(fileName,'rb') as fileHandle:
     compressedFileName = "%s-1.gz" % fileName
     with gzip.open(compressedFileName, 'wb') as compressedFH:
        compressedFH.writelines(fileHandle)

  finalTime = time.time() - startTime
  print("gzipFile=%s fileName=%s" % (finalTime,compressFileName))
```

Comment: Have you explored [`bzip2`](http://www.bzip.org/)?

Comment: @delnan I was suggesting the standalone utility; not _implementing_ it.

Comment: @devnull That makes more sense, though it may be desirable to avoid dependencies and not shell out more processes. (I wasn't talking about implementing it either, i was talking about using the Python bindings).

Comment: First glance at this title, and I was like "Um, pad 724GB worth of zeros? Not really compressing, but ok."

Answer (score 3):

```
with gzip.open(compressedFileName, 'wb') as compressedFH:
    compressedFH.writelines(fileHandle)
```

writes the file `fileHandle` *line by line*, i. e. splits it into chunks separated by the `\n` character.

While it is quite probable that this character occurs from time to time in a binary file as well, this is not guaranteed.

It might be better to do

```
with gzip.open(compressedFileName, 'wb') as compressedFH:
    while True:
        chunk = fileHandle.read(65536)
        if not chunk: break # the while loop
        compressedFH.write(chunk)
```

or, as tqzf writes in a comment,

```
with gzip.open(compressedFileName, 'wb') as compressedFH:
    shutil.copyfileobj(fileHandle, compressedFileName)
```

Comment: There is already an implementation of this in the standard lib: `shutil.copyfileobj(fileHandle, compressedFileName, [optional buffer size parameter])` (wait, why are we camelcasing python again?).

Answer (score 2):

```
from subprocess import call
call(["tar", "-pczf name_of_your_archive.tar.gz /path/to/directory"])
```

Run it externally, simplest way and probably fastest.

Comment: Yep, I am looking at more pythonic way of doing with gzip.

Comment: @Richard don't force yourself into staying in Python, you will get into a lot of trouble. Python implementation overflows 30GB limit meaning it is not optimized and probably takes a lot of time. For long operations, like compression, ALWAYS use fast approach, in this case tar gzip command that will speed things up.

Comment: @Migol Thanks. I will use an alternative method.I have successfully split 100GB file into 2GB chunks(file offsets) and compressed them in memory. I tried to compress the whole file in one shot and boom process is killed.